# CATV Voltage Levels

Tags: rf, protection, surge-protection

What are typical and maximum allowed voltage levels at a CATV coaxial cable?

Looking at some datasheets for GDTs and some Coaxial Surge Arrestor manuals I'm seeing a big range of breakover voltages, ranging from 27 to 300 VDC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to "[the Real Cable Guy](http://www.therealcableguy.com/tv-signal-levels.htm)":

> To measure a particular CATV RF signal at a given frequency we use a new unit: the dBmV - the decibel-millivolt. Early on in cabledom, it was observed that a television set required about 0.001 volts - or 1 millivolt - to display a good picture. So 1 mV became the reference point for CATV RF Signal measurement. Since a tv is designed to offer 75 ohms impedance, 1 mV across 75 ohms resistance became the CATV measurement of 0 dBmV. Also important to note is the fact that decibels are logarithmic and not linear; so negative dBmV levels still have meaning.

[Other](http://www.digitalhome.ca/forum/showpost.php?p=433265&postcount=18) [sources](http://www.tselectronic.com/tech_notes/db.php) cite 0 dBmV as a typical target, -10 dBmV as the minimum useful threshold for digital signals and +16dBmV as a 'maximum'.

Most digital cable and DTV satellite systems use RG-6 coaxial cable. The center conductor is 18AWG, which is considered suitable for 2.3A (for power transmission). 2kV insulation between the conductor and shield is typical. The most likely reason the GDTs are so high is that they're intended for lightning strike protection - not due to excessively-strong CATV signals.

Comment: I am thinking in terms of typical tolerances for cable boxes and modems, I couldn't find any reference on maximum values.